# How do I determine when all animations inside an element have ended?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I'm trying to add or remove a class from a wrapper element after several CSS animations on items inside it have completed. The number of items may vary as well as their animation duration. Animations are described with the aid of CSS classes that are removed once each animation ends.

```js
  function transitionToShown() {
    backdrop.classList.add(CLASS_TRANSITIONING_IN);
    dialog.classList.add(CLASS_TRANSITIONING_IN);

    backdrop.addEventListener(
      "animationend",
      () => {
        backdrop.classList.remove(CLASS_TRANSITIONING_IN);
      },
      { once: true }
    );
    dialog.addEventListener(
      "animationend",
      () => {
        dialog.classList.remove(CLASS_TRANSITIONING_IN);
      },
      { once: true }
    );

    wrapper.addEventListener(
      ??How do I add/remove classes on the wrapper after animations on the dialog and backdrop have ended?? 
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using promises along with the Web Animations API seems like a simple solution for this. Even if the Web Animations API is listed as experimental, it is widely supported across modern browsers.

```js
Promise.all(
  wrapper.getAnimations({ subtree: true }).map(function (animation) {
    return animation.finished;
  })
).then(function () {
  return wrapper.classList.remove(CLASS_SHOWN);
});
```